# Prove that $f_n(B_{\tau_1 } , \dots, B_{\tau_{n-1 }}, -1) < B_{\tau_{n-1 }} < f_n(B_{\tau_1 } , \dots, B_{\tau_{n-1 }}, 1)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

> I would like to prove that (almost surely)
>
> $$f_n(B_{\tau_1 } , \dots, B_{\tau_{n-1 }}, -1) < B_{\tau_{n-1 }} < f_n(B_{\tau_1 } , \dots, B_{\tau_{n-1 }}, 1)$$

Where the context is as follows: we have a martingale $(X_n )$ - with expectation equal to zero - such that for each $n \ge 1$ there exists a Borel measurable function $f_n: \ \mathbb {R } ^{-1 } \times \{-1, 1 \}  \to \mathbb R$, and a $\{-1 , 1 \} $- valued random variable $D_n $ such that

$$X_n = f_n(X_1, \dots , X_{n-1 } , D_n )$$

Further we assume that for any $x_1, \dots, x_{n-1 } $

$$f_n(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1 } , -1 ) < f_n(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1 } , 1 )$$

> Given a Brownian motion $(B_t)$ we define the stopping times $\tau_0 = 0$ and for $n \ge 1$
>
> $$\tau_n = \inf \{t > \tau_{n-1 }: \ B_t \in \{f_n(B_{\tau_1 } ,\dots, B_{\tau_{n-1 } }, -1 ), f_n(B_{\tau_1 } ,\dots, B_{\tau_{n-1 } }, 1 ) \} \}   $$

---

This is what I manage to do:

For $n=1 $ we have that $f_1 : \{-1, 1 \} \to \mathbb{R}$, and since $f_1(D_1)=X_1 $ and $E[X_1]=E[X_0]=0$, we get

$$0 = E[f_1(D_1)]=f_1(-1)P[D_1=-1] + f_1(d)P[D_1=1]$$

By the assumption that $f_1(-1) < f_1(1)$ this means that $f(-1)<0<f_1(1)$. And since $\tau_0 = 0$ and $B_0 = 0$ the claim holds for $n=1$.

For general $n $ we have again that

$$E[f_n(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1 } , D_n )] = 0$$

And hence

\begin{multline*}
    E[f_n(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1 } , D_n )] = \\
    = E[f_n(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1 } , -1 )1_{\{D_n = -1\}}] + E[f_n(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1 } , 1 )1_{\{D_n = 1\}}] = 0
\end{multline*}

This means that one of the integrals must be negative and one positive [or both equal to zero]. But here I got stuck!

> How is it possible to relate the value of $f_n(B_{\tau_1 } , \dots B_{\tau_{n-1 } } , \pm 1 ) $ to $B_{\tau_{n-1 } } $?

Much grateful for any help provided!

Comment: From your another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3610574/prove-that-the-following-sequence-is-a-binary-splittting) I guess that the context is partially missing. Namely, in that question, $f_n(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1},1) = \mathrm{E}[X \mid X>X_{n-1}]$ and $f_n(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1},-1) = \mathrm{E}[X \mid X<X_{n-1}]$, which immediately implies the desired inequality.

Comment: @zhoraster No, I don't think I may assume that. In the question you are referring to the context is that we construct a "binary splitting martingale" from a random variable $X $. The context in this question is that we assume that we there exists a "binary splitting martingale" and then use that to show that there exists stopping times $\tau_n $ such that $0 \le \tau_1, \tau_2 \dots $ and $X_n \sim B_{\tau_n }$.  In particular no such random variable $X $ is mention in this later context.

Comment: Or put in an other way: I don't think we may assume that $(X_n) $ is constructed in this particular way.

Comment: Ok, I see. Anyway, it follows from the third inequality (following the words "further we assume") and the assumtion that $X_n$ is a martingale.

Comment: I don't understand. What follows from the third inequality and the fact that $X_n $ is a martingale? That $X_n $ must be constructed in the particular way $X_n=E[X | \mathcal F_n] $ for some random variable $X $, and $\mathcal F_n = \sigma(D_1, \dots D_n) $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the martingale property with the inequality $f_n(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1 } , -1 ) < f_n(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1 } , 1 )$ and assuming that $\mathrm P(D_n = 1\mid \mathcal F_{n-1})\notin \{0,1\}$ a.s., we have
$$
X_{n-1} = \mathrm E[X_n \mid \mathcal F_{n-1}] = \mathrm E[f_n(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1},D_n) \mid \mathcal F_{n-1}] \\
= f_n(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1},1)\cdot \mathrm P(D_n = 1\mid \mathcal F_{n-1}) \\+ f_n(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1},-1)\cdot \mathrm P(D_n = -1\mid \mathcal F_{n-1})\\
< f_n(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1},1)\cdot \mathrm P(D_n = 1\mid \mathcal F_{n-1})\\ + f_n(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1},{\color{red}1})\cdot \mathrm P(D_n = -1\mid \mathcal F_{n-1})\\
= f_n(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1},1).
$$
Similarly, 
$$
X_{n-1} > f_n(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1},-1)\cdot \mathrm P(D_n = 1\mid \mathcal F_{n-1})\\ + f_n(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1},-1)\cdot \mathrm P(D_n = -1\mid \mathcal F_{n-1})
= f_n(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1},-1).
$$

Comment: Okey, so then for $n=2 $ we would have $ \tau_{1 } = \inf \{t>0: B_t \in \{f_1(-1), f_1(1) \} \}$. Thus $B_{\tau_1 } $ equals $f_1(-1) $ or $f_1(1)$. 

Then it should be the case that 

$$f_2(f_1(-1), -1 ) < f_1(-1) < f_2(f_1(-1) , 1)$$

and 

$$f_2(f_1(-1), -1 ) < f_1(-1) < f_2(f_1(-1) , 1)$$

If we take $\omega$ such that $X_1( \omega) = f(-1)$, then the first inequality above follows from the initial inequality you showed, and simarily for an $\omega $ such that $X_1(\omega) = f_1(1)$ for the second. Then I should do this for general $n $ as well? Is that right?

Comment: 1) "Okey, so then for $n=2$" did you mean $n=1$? 2) "Then it should be the case that ... and ..." I see no difference between these two inequalities. Perhaps, the second should involve $f_1(1)$ in place of $f_1(-1)$. 3) "Then I should do this for general $n$" What "this"?

Comment: To late to edit my comment now. But the second inequality should be $f_2(f_1(1), -1) < f_1(-1) < f_2(f_1(1), -1)$ and I mean that this corresponds to those $\omega$:s such that $\tau_1(\omega)= f_1(-1) $ and $f_1(1) $ respectively.

Comment: ... Which is nonsense (the left-hand side and the right-hand side are the same). I believe it should be $f_2(f_1(1), -1) < f_1(1) < f_2(f_1(1), 1)$.

Comment: This would prove the inequality $f_2(B_{\tau_1 } , -1) < B_{\tau_1 }< f_2(B_{\tau_1 } , 1) $

Comment: Yes you are right!

Comment: Okey so I can see now that 
$$f(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1 },-1 ) < X_{n-1 } < f(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1 }, 1)$$

implies

$$f_n(B_{\tau_1 } , \dots, B_{\tau_{n-1 }}, -1) < B_{\tau_{n-1 }} < f_n(B_{\tau_1 } , \dots, B_{\tau_{n-1 }}, 1)$$ 
And  I posted what I did below.

Answer (score 0):

Following zhoraster's answer I felt that the last step was missing. At least it wansn't obvious to me. So below is what I would try to do. *I'm sorry for the argument being extremely long winded. Hopefully there is a better way than this!*

That is I would like to show that

\begin{equation}
f(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1 },-1 ) < X_{n-1 } < f(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1 }, 1)
\end{equation}

implies

$$f_n(B_{\tau_1 } , \dots, B_{\tau_{n-1 }}, -1) < B_{\tau_{n-1 }} < f_n(B_{\tau_1 } , \dots, B_{\tau_{n-1 }}, 1)$$

**For $n=2 $**  we would have $ \tau_{1 } = \inf \{t>0: B_t \in \{f_1(-1), f_1(1) \} \}$. Thus $B_{\tau_1 } $ equals either $f_1(-1) $ or $f_1(1)$ that is $\tau_1 $ may only take two different values.

For

$$f_2(B_{\tau_1 }, -1) < B_{\tau_1}  < f_n(B_{\tau_1 }, 1)$$

to hold it should thus be the case that

$$f_2(f_1(-1), -1 ) < f_1(-1) < f_2(f_1(-1) , 1)$$

and

$$f_2(f_1(1), -1 ) < f_1(1) < f_2(f_1(1) , 1)$$

If we take $\omega$ such that $X_1( \omega) = f(-1)$, then the first inequality above follows from (1), and similarly do the second above for an $\omega $ such that $X_1(\omega) = f_1(1)$.

**For $n=3$** we would have $\tau_2 = \inf \{t > \tau_1 : B_t \in \{f_2(B_{\tau_1 } ,-1), f_2(B_{\tau_1 } ,1 ) \} \} $

and we should show that

$$f_3(B_{\tau_1 }, B_{\tau_2 } , -1 ) < B_{\tau_2 } < f_2(B_{\tau_1 }, B_{\tau_2} ,1)$$

Thus given $\omega $ we must consider first what values $B_{\tau_1 } $ and $B_{\tau_2 }$  may take and then consider if the two inequalities hold for those values. As shown in the previous step $\tau_1 $ may only take the values $f_1(-1) $ or $f_1(1) $.  Thus $\tau_2 $ may be written

$$ 
\tau_2 =
\begin{cases}
\inf \{t > f_1(-1): B_t \in \{f_2(f_1(-1), -1), \ f_2(f_1(-1), 1)\} \} &\text {if } \tau_1 = f_1(-1) \\
\inf \{t > f_1(1): B_t \in \{f_2(f_1(1), -1), \ f_2(f_1(1), 1)\} \} &\text {if } \tau_1 = f_1(1)
\end{cases}
$$

Say that $\omega $ is such that $\tau_1(\omega)=f_1(1)$ and $\tau_2(\omega)= f_2(f_1(1), 1)$, then for

$$f_3(B_{\tau_1 }( \omega), B_{\tau_1 }(\omega) , -1 ) < B_{\tau_2 }(\omega) < f_2(B_{\tau_1 }(\omega), B_{\tau_2}(\omega) ,1)$$

to be true we should have

$$f_3(f_1(1), \ f_2(f_1(1), 1), -1) < f_2(f_1(1), \ 1) < f_3(f_1(1), \ f_2(f_1(1), 1), 1) $$

If there exists $\omega $ such that $X_1(\omega) = f_1(1) $ and $X_2(\omega) = f_2(f_1(1), 1) $ then the last equality follows from

$$f_3(X_1, X_2, -1) < X_2 < f_2(X_1, X_2, 1)$$

and simarily for the other possible values of $\tau_1 $ and $\tau_2 $.

*I suppose we could expand this argument using induction to hold for any $n $.*